# Multiple unique click events

Tags: jquery, image, resize, counter

I don't really have an idea on how to phrase this question--even the title may be a bit misleading.

**Scenario:**
I'm using jquery to create a function when an element with the specific class is clicked.

When the element is clicked, it looks for an image in the element passed by the parameters and resizes (increase) the image using animate().

Here's the code I hacked together:

```
            var counter = 2;
          $(".bigger").click(function(event,ui) {
                var objid       = $(this).attr("rel"); 
                var mainid      = $(this).attr("id"); 
                var imageid = "#"+objid+""; 
                $(imageid).find('img').animate({ height:objheight * counter,width: objwidth * counter}).css({ height: objheight * counter, width: objwidth * counter });                
                    counter++;


            });
```

objheight and objwidth are the dimensions of the image.

HTML

```
<li class="ui-widget-content" id="obj1">
<img src="elements/pic1.png" id="obj_1" class="ui-widget-content"  width="96" height="72" />
<div class="tools"><a class="ui-icon sizeup" rel="obj1"  id="obj_1"  href=""><span></span></a>
```

Problem:
Since the counter is incremented whenever the click happens, when I have multiple images I want to resize instead of starting from var counter = 2; It just picks up from the increment..which is understandable, however, how can I stop this from happening? A unique counter for each element? How can I create that?

Thanks for any help as always.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, your HTML code is invalid. Two elements must not share the same `id`. And you really should make it more explicit. `obj_1` / `obj1` doesn't feel right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [data API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to store metadata for DOM elements.

For example:

```
$(".bigger").click(function(event,ui) {
  var objid       = $(this).attr("rel"); 
  var mainid      = $(this).attr("id"); 
  var imageid = "#"+objid; 
  var image = $(imageid).find('img');
  var counter = (image.data('counter') || 1) + 1;
  image.data('counter', counter);
  image.animate({ height: objheight * counter,width: objwidth * counter});
  $('#result').html(image.data('counter'));
});​
```

You can check this work on the [jsFiddle I just made for testing](http://jsfiddle.net/7EXRd/2/).

Comment: Plugged this in, nothing happens on the click event. When I set alert (counter) to see what's being ran, it comes back as undefined.

Comment: On first click, `counter` will be undefined. On subsequent clicks, it should increase as expected. Can you share the code you used for testing?

Comment: Well. Tweaked some things in the code. You can check the jsFiddle to see it at work: http://jsfiddle.net/7EXRd/1/

Answer (score -1):

There is a bug in your code, it's illegal to use same ID img and a have id="obj_1"... You can replace it with data-id.
I've used previous answer, to show that you can use data settings right in html code to predefine data.

http://jsfiddle.net/SqarV/